# How can i install SPE(Stani's Python Editor) for python3.3

Tags: server, 13.10, python, python-2.7, python3

I have ubuntu 13.10.I have SPE which runs for python2.7.4+.But i need to run it for python 3.3.2+.How can i do it.My system uses python2.7.4+ by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stani's Python editor package in Ubuntu repos depends on Python 2.*

You will not be able to run in on Python 3.

If you install the `spe` package it will automatically install all necessary packages including python 2.*

Comment: Yes, it "repo" means "repository"